# Supported account types set for all accounts in Azure AD, Still not able to sign-in the application with personal account

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am following a tutorial [Build Java apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java)

and after using my **personal account** for Azure AD to register the application. I am not able to sign in using my personal account but I set the support account as 'Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts. Any help?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeXPG.png)

Comment: Are you using the `/common` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `/tenant id` endpoint to the `/common` endpoint.

> The `/tenant id` endpoint only allows users with work/school accounts
> of a specific Azure AD tenant to log in to the application. It does
> not support personal accounts.
>
> Only the `/common` endpoints will allow personal Microsoft accounts to
> log in to the application.

Comment: while registering the app in AD I set the Redirect URI as  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient . Does that set the desired endpoint?

Comment: @ShambhaviTewari  I'm talking about the url when logging in to the app, not the url that is redirected after logging in.

Comment: @ShambhaviTewari  For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request

Comment: [login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/deviceauth](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/deviceauth) this is the endpoint where it asks for credentials and give a response of an access token after authorizing.